# Predicate for reuseable datetime filter

Tags: c#, date, filter, predicate

I have a number of objects that contain a datetime. I have found that I am reusing the lambda statement:

```
Where(x => EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(x.Date.Value) >= EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(startDate) &&
    EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(x.Date.Value) <= EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(endDate));
```

in a number of locations.  I would like to replace this expression with a single predicate that can be used on my List of objects with a date.

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_.

Comment: Are you looking for `DateTime.Date`?  More specifically, how does `EntityFunctions.TruncateTime` differ from `DateTime.Date`?

Comment: Are `startDate` and `endDate` locals, or class level variables?

Comment: I basically have a List<IDateable>, each object has a Date property.

The startDate and endDate would be a range that I could pass in.  

Based on what I have read so far, I believe it would look something like: 

List<IDateable> newList = myList.Find(IsInRange(DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddDays(7)); 

I have tried to set this up both as a predicate and a Func<DateTime, DateTime, bool>.  

@AustinSalonen - The EnitityFunctions.TruncateTime is built into .Net to allow you to ignore the Time portion of a DateTime object when using Entity Framework in lambda expressions.

Comment: @JohnSaunders - thank you for the link.  In the future, I will try to improve my initial questions and give more detail as to what I have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `startDate` and `endDate` are class level variables, you could just use a method:

```
bool FilterDate(YourEntityType x)
{
    return EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(x.Date.Value) >= EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(startDate) &&
           EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(x.Date.Value) <= EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(endDate));
}
```

This would then be called via:

```
var results = myobjects.Where(FilterDate);
```

However, if they are locals, your lambda is closing over two local variables (`startDate` and `endDate`), which could cause the behavior to change if you reused a single delegate, unless the scope was always kept the same.

One option could be to make a helper method:

```
static Func<YourEntityType, bool> CreateFilter(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
     Func<YourEntityType, bool> func = x => EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(x.Date.Value) >= EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(startDate) &&
EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(x.Date.Value) <= EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(endDate));
     return func;
}
```

You could then write this as:

```
var results = myobjects.Where(CreateFilter(startDate, endDate));
```

Comment: Reed, I believe this pretty close to what I am trying to achieve.  I had not considered using a helper function. I will give this a try later today.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Define another predicate method, that will check if `YourType` has a correct date

```
private static bool IsObjectHasNeccesaryDate(YourType obj, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
    return EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(obj.Date.Value) >= EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(startDate) 
        && EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(obj.Date.Value) <= EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(endDate);
}
```

Then you can use it using lambda syntax, like so:

```
myobjects.Where(obj => IsObjectHasNeccesaryDate(obj, startDate, endDate));
```

Note that it will capture your `startDate` and `endDate` variables.

Comment: This will only work if `startDate` and `endDate` are class level variables, and not locals.

Comment: updated my answer. Thanks for noting. Made that predicate static, so that to apparent, that he doesn't access private object's state

Answer (score 1):

You can define your expression as a Func:

```
Func<object,bool> exp = x => 
    EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(x.Date.Value) >= EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(startDate) 
    && EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(x.Date.Value) <= EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(endDate);
```

Replacing object with whatever the type is you're working with.  Then pass the Func to the Where:

```
Where(exp);
```